# SSAS queries run in 0ms. Going through SSRS they take 1.3 seconds

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssas, mdx, olap

these queries show up as running in 0ms using SSMS/SSAS natively.

but when I send them through Reporting Services, they're showing up as 1.3 seconds. That is ~1300 times slower than 0ms.

I know I'm a little bit rusty on MDX, but I'd LOVE it if someone would take a look at this.

I'm using SQL Enterprise, the SSAS server is an I7 desktop with SSD.

```
="SELECT NON EMPTY {[Measures].[Cost Amt] } ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY { 
([Vendor].[Vendor].ALLMEMBERS * [Cost Code].[Cost Code].ALLMEMBERS ) 
} ON ROWS 
FROM [DspAlloc] 
WHERE [InvoiceNumber].[All InvoiceNumber].[" + Parameters!InvoiceNumber.Value + 
"] CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING,
FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS"

="SELECT NON EMPTY { 
[Measures].[Total Freight], [Measures].[Incl Frt], [Measures].[Total Qty],
[Measures].[Total Ship Wt] } ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY { ([Item_No].[Item_No].ALLMEMBERS ) } ON ROWS 
FROM [InvoiceDetail] 
WHERE [InvoiceNumber].[All InvoiceNumber].[" + Parameters!InvoiceNumber.Value + 
"] CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING,
FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS"
```

Comment: Where are you establishing that the query takes 1.3 seconds? Are you using the SQL Server Profiler? Reason I ask is that it could be a reporting services connectivity issues and not SSAS?

Comment: yes, I think that it's SSRS issue.. not SSAS issue.. Let me upload some stats.. 

SELECT ReportPath, AVG(TimeDataRetrieval), AVG(TimeProcessing), AVG(TimeRendering)
FROM ReportServer.dbo.ExecutionLog2
WHERE ReportPath LIKE '%CubeReports%'
AND TimeEnd between '10/17/2012' and '2012-10-18 11:54:25.130'
GROUP BY ReportPath

Comment: /rptSubRptDetailAllocations 1404ms = AvgTimeDataRetrieval
/rptSubRptInvoiceItems 1261ms = AvgTimeDataRetrieval

Comment: TimeProcessing and TimeRendering are a total of 50-80ms.